# Conditions under which a function with zero divergence is constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ with zero divergence, $\nabla \cdot f = 0$ everywhere. Suppose that the function is zero on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example, I'm interested in a function that is $0$ for all $\textbf{x} = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with $x_i <0$ for some $1 \leq i \leq n$. For $n=2$ this reduces to a function that is zero on quadrants II, III and IV. Is it then true that $f=0$ everywhere?

For instance, for $n=1$, if $f(x) = 0$ for $x<0$, then $f'(x)=0$ everywhere implies that $f=0$. But it is not easy to see whether this holds for the divergence in higher dimensions.

More generally, given a function with zero divergence, are there conditions under which the function is constant?

Comment: The function needs to take values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to compute the divergence.  The divergence isn't defined for scalar functions.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, sorry I miswrote the function definition.